# Is there a decentralized database for collecting primary historical records?

Tags: databases

Is there a decentralized storage protocol for housing a database of primary records that would be used in historical research, for example, events to have occurred in a certain year, and primary records we have from the time, like newspaper articles?

By decentralized, I mean that choices governing the properties of the database are not easily affected by individual human choice.

For example, in a company, a CEO may be able to change the system they are running quickly.

In some systems based on voting and consensus, it is possible that the properties of the system are easy to change by the exertion of human will. If someone rallies public support for something, it is possible to accomplish a change that was desired by that group of people.

In a decentralized system, all of the actors or participants have roughly equal participation. Although what kind of participation is open to definition, I would say that a winner-takes-all type system lacks decentralization regarding the effect sizes of individual choices.

In some ways, my idea of decentralization (coming from blockchain) can be named “inflexibility”. Like Bitcoin, I am not sure anyone can successfully stop it or shut it down (but I don’t know). I do not think anyone is really “running” it. It appears to be an emergent phenomenon (even if not invulnerable).

Is there such a database?

Comment: Are you talking about digital historical records?

Comment: It's unclear to me what type of historical records you're interested in. Are you interested in digitized documents, audio files, and other media formats? Are you purely interested in the records? How would your database be any different from the Internet, a library, or any number of databases a uni subscribes to?